# How to number pages in Acrobat Pro DC?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

In previous versions of Acrobat Pro, I can number pages in roman numbers like i, ii, iii, ix, x,... (So that I can type these numbers to jump to the given pages.)

But I don't find such an option in Acrobat Pro DC. Can anybody how to do this on MacOSX?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to View -> Show/Hide -> Navigation Panes -> Page Thumbnails (or click the thumbnails icon)
2. The page thumbnails window will show on the left. Select the pages you would like to make roman numerals.
3. Click on the options icon and select "Page Labels..."

[image: Page Labels]

Comment: I am not asking to add the roman numerals to headers. I want to change the page labels to roman numerals so that I can jump to a page using roman numerals. This function was able in Acrobat Pro X, I just don't know where it is in Acrobat Pro DC.

Comment: @user1424739 I have updated my answer. Let me know if I have still not answered your question.